# liferay, how to add a new permission to liferay using admin panel portal

Tags: permissions, liferay, roles

adding a new permission to liferay

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW1Pq.png)

first, i need to add new category, for example, after control panel i need to add "pages",
and inside the "pages" i need to add all the pages that i created and each one give the role the permission that i want, and after the "pages" i want to add for example "Status" and inside it there is all the status i have and each one give the permission to the role.